# Combine queries on the same table in LiteDB

Tags: c#, litedb

I am using LiteDB, and trying to improve performance. I currently have two queries on the same table, and was wondering if there is another way to combine these two queries as one to improve performance.

```
            using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_databaseFileName))
            {
                // Get a collection (or create, if doesn't exist)
                var collection = db.GetCollection<IdentityKeyPair>(_tableName);

                collection.EnsureIndex(x => x.Value);
                collection.EnsureIndex(x => x.RecordId);

                var entityKeyRecordId = collection.Query().Where(p => p.Value == uniqueValue).Select(x => x.RecordId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (entityKeyRecordId != Guid.Empty)
                    results = collection.Query().Where(p => p.RecordId == entityKeyRecordId).ToList();

            }
```

Comment: So you only need the results of the second query?

Comment: Yes, only need results from the second query

Comment: Value is unique, but RecordId is not?

Comment: Yes, value is unique and recordId is not.

Comment: Oh, it's NoSQL. Consider embedded document/array instead of a flattened collection. As you see, it has to scan the index twice, thus in 2 separate queries.

Comment: we had to do it like that for other performance reasons

Comment: If it is like MongoDB, you can still index on embedded array.